# How to draw a quartic Bezier curve in inkscape

Tags: bezier, inkscape, cubic-bezier

When I draw a cubic bezier curve with 4 control points,
I choose regular bezier path,
draw a line, then drag 2 handles out.

[image]

[image]

But now, I need draw a quartic curve with 5 control points.
I don't know how to do it.
[image]

How can I add the 5th control points in to handles?
Am I right to consider handles as control points?

Thank you, friends~~

Comment: The SVG specification doesn't include 4th-degree Bezier curves, and so neither does Inkscape. SVG has 3rd-degree (cubic, 4 control points), 2nd-degree (quadratic, 3 control points), and 1st-degree (linear, 2 control points) Bezier curves. Cubic Bezier curves allow independent control of the path endpoints and tangents. Why do you need a 4th-degree Bezier curve? Consider using a cubic Bezier path with two or more segments. https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for a BSpline path rather than a regular Bezier path. This is the 3rd mode available (see your 1st attached screenshot).

Regular Bezier will interpolate (go through) your control points. BSpline is the classic N-degree Bézier.